# Having a modified relativenumber

Tags: options, line-numbers

In my experience with vim I found relative numbers pretty useful. But I would like to know if is there an argument I could give to the my neovim configuration file so I could configure it in such way that **relative numbers stay the same but in the current line number it actually displays the line I am at and not just the number 0**. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's my everyday configuration. Just set both of these...

```
:set relativenumber
:set number
```

If, for example, the cursor is on line 50 you'd see

```
..
 2
 1
50
 1
 2
..
```

That's it!

Comment: @B Layer yup :)